# How to activate a virtual environment in Ubuntu?

Tags: python3, virtualenv

I installed `virtualenv` and I created a virtual environment inside my directory. Everything is OK, but I can't activate it. When I run:

```
source /bin/activate
```

it says:

```
already: command not found
```

Screenshot:

[image: img_virtualenv]

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please do not have pictures of text, always include the text in the body of the question so everyone can see it. The error is clear in the directory you are running the command from it does not exist.

Comment: but i run this command almost in every directory...it is only working in home/ directory....but not working in side a folder which is also in home

Comment: A virtualenv only works in a specific directory. You get to specify the directory when you create the venv. This does not seem like an Ubuntu-related question. This seems like a how-do-I-use-python-venv question. There are some good examples at https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html.

Answer (score 13):

You need to install `python3-venv`:

```
sudo apt install python3-venv
```

Then:

```
python3 -m venv vvv
source vvv/bin/activate
```

Comment: the last line was the answer I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

if your virtual environment name is "venv", you can use below command to switch there:

source venv/bin/activate

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLgry.png)

referance :  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2W_YE0fZs88

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of another answer to this question. How is this answer different?